# Facebook Notifications Replacement

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, dashboard

There seem to be many questions about this, but so far I can't find any definitive answers.  What is the best alternative to the depreciated notifications.send method, such that I can send a notification to users through my app?

The last time I looked into this, the answer seemed to be to use the dashboard API, using counters and dashboard activity streams, and possibly augmenting by posting to users' walls directly.  I also remember my app getting disabled after requesting too many stream_publish requests, and I assume this is still the case...

So to conclude, I'm just curious if Facebook has presented a straight-forward alternative to Notifications yet, aside from the Dashboard API.  I don't think there's Graph API support for it yet, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages, email and sms are ok, but as far as I can find, the Request Dialog is their intended direct replacement.  Sending these out increment the dashboard counters, too.
The caveat with these is that if you want to send them out through the API, you can only send them to people that have accepted your app.  The user must send them out for them to reach out to new users.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the notifications api was essentially killed with still no replacement.  The best available workaround is using Facebook messages, e-mail or SMS.